# What is the recommended mongo db plugin for Play! Framework?

Tags: java, scala, plugins, mongodb, playframework

There are at least two mongo db plug-ins for Play! Framework, [PlayMorphia](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia) and [Mongo 1.3](http://www.playframework.org/modules/mongo).

What is the recommended plug-in, and if there is other, what about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the morphia module. It has more functionality, uses another well tested library and is in a way better shape.

Answer (score 0):

consider also reading this article if you are interested in Play Framework 2.0, which was released recently: http://nesbot.com/2011/11/28/play-2-morphia-logging-error

Answer (score 0):

I've recently written a mongodb plugin for play (scala)

https://github.com/leon/play-salat

have a look!

Answer (score 0):

All those two is for play 1.x . If you use play 2.x you can give play-salat or Play-ReactiveMongo a try.

play-salat : https://github.com/leon/play-salat

Play-ReactiveMongo: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo

By the way Leon Radley ,when play-salat will support play 2.2 version??